# Exchange Journaling - What happens with delivery failure on certain recipients

Tags: exchange, journal

If there are three users (A, B, C) in an exchange (O365 or recent Exch versions), and there is an incoming email To: A, B, C, where B and C got some delivery failures, will the exchange journal report mention only A?  Are there any resources that talk about journaling behaviors in-depth?  I searched, couldn't find any..

One more question, can we assume the exchange journal report as source of truth for the message-delivery?

Answer (score 0):

I have done a test in my lab, if the a message was sent to user01 and user02, and the user02 delivery failed, the exchange journal report mention only user01, the below is the testing screenshots for your reference:
[image]

And you also receive the NDR for the journal for the failed delivery for user02:
[image]

For more details on Journaling in Exchange Server for your reference: [Journaling in Exchange Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/policy-and-compliance/journaling/journaling?view=exchserver-2019)